# Need to associate gpa calculator with fillable form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment that requires a student to enter their status (Undergrad/Graduate). After they enter their status a series of questions asking for GPA pop up depending on status. I was able to figure this part out. 
The next part requires a GPA calculator based on the letter grades entered. This is where I am confused.
I am trying to associate my form with the GPA calculator, but it is not working. I am also not certain that my calculator is complete.

I created a new function and variable for the calculator, but cannot associate it to the answers provided in the form that the student completes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Student Summer Position</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(){
var shSelect = document.getElementById("showhideSelect");
var shStt = shSelect.value;
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
if (shStt == "div1") {
div1.style.display = "block";
div2.style.display = "none";
}
else {
div1.style.display = "none";
div2.style.display = "block";
}
}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<h3> Student Status </h3>

<form id="showhideform">
<p> Please select your student status </p>
<select id="showhideSelect" onchange="showhide()">
  <option value="div1">Undergrad</option>
  <option value="div2">Graduate</option>
</select>

</form>
<div id="div1">
<br>
  Class 1:<br>
  <input id=input1 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 2:<br>
  <input id=input2 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 3:<br>
  <input id=input3 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none"> 
<br>
  Class 1:<br>
  <input id=input1 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 2:<br>
  <input id=input2 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 3:<br>
  <input id=input3 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
 </div>

<div>
var gradeValues = {
    "A": 4.0,
    "B": 3.0,
    "C": 2.0,
    "D": 1.0,
    "F": 0
};
<\div>

<script>
var getGrade = function() {
    input1 = document.form.input1.value;
    input2 = document.form.input2.value;
    input3 = document.form.input3.value;
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML =
((gradeValues[input1] + gradeValues[input2] + gradeValues[input3]) / 3) + " is your GPA";
}
<\script> 

</body>
</html>
```

The part where the student identifies their status as a student works and shows respective drop down. I cannot get it to associate with the GPA calculator and am not sure if the calculator is formatted correctly.

Comment: Some js is out of a script tag, and you miss the callback for the form, if not how the grade function will work?

Comment: @greedo Can you help me out by showing sample code. I am racking my brain over this, but have not been able to run the second part of this code. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct working solution of your code:

```js
var gradeValues = {
    "A": 4.0,
    "B": 3.0,
    "C": 2.0,
    "D": 1.0,
    "F": 0
};

function getGrade() {
    input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
    document.getElementById("div3").innerHTML =
((gradeValues[input1] + gradeValues[input2] + gradeValues[input3]) / 3) + " is your GPA";
}

function showhide(){
  var shSelect = document.getElementById("showhideSelect");
  var shStt = shSelect.value;
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
  if (shStt == "div1") {
    div1.style.display = "block";
    div2.style.display = "none";
  }else {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Student Summer Position</title>

</head>

<body>
<h3> Student Status </h3>

<form id="showhideform">
<p> Please select your student status </p>
<select id="showhideSelect" onchange="showhide()">
  <option value="div1">Undergrad</option>
  <option value="div2">Graduate</option>
</select>

</form>
<div id="div1">
<br>
  Class 1:<br>
  <input id=input1 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 2:<br>
  <input id=input2 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 3:<br>
  <input id=input3 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none"> 
<br>
  Class 1:<br>
  <input id=input1 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 2:<br>
  <input id=input2 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
  <br>
  Class 3:<br>
  <input id=input3 type="text" name="Lettergrade" value="">
 </div>
 <button onclick="getGrade()">get GPA!</button>
 <div id="div3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```